# Ruby Error in cocoa pods After upgrading os and installing xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, rubygems, cocoapods

I got the following error when i run terminal command

`pod install` 
command in terminal

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn (LoadError)
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:1395:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `require'
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'

JAYDEEPs-Mini:~ jaydeepvyas$ rvm -v
rvm 1.29.6 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]

JAYDEEPs-Mini:~ jaydeepvyas$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
JAYDEEPs-Mini:~ jaydeepvyas$
```

Comment: What version of rubygems do you have? I found this happening in Docker (building ruby from source) with rubygems 3.0.0 but not with 2.7.4.

Comment: @jwadsack unable to install pods .. When I tried to update brew giving the same error

Comment: -bash: brew: command not found with brew

Comment: @jwadsack i added verision in question

Comment: Can you check `gem --version` and see if that is 3.0.0? If it is, try running `gem update --system 2.7.4` and see if that gets you going. I don't know where the problem is, but that worked for my issue at the moment.

Comment: This is being discussed on rubygems Github issues [2535](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2535) and [2541](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2541) and may have something to do with `rubygems` 3.0.0 installed by root which is then only accessible by root (see the second issue).

Answer (score 1):

running sudo gem update --system 2.7.4 and you can solve this question

Comment: Only thing that actually worked! Added -n /usr/local/bin on my system too, cause /usr/bin wasn't writable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`gem` had new [release 3.0.1](https://blog.rubygems.org/2018/12/23/3.0.1-released.html) contains the fix, issue related https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2535

Try `gem update --system`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me based on rimkashox answer

sudo gem update --system 2.7.4 -n /usr/local/bin