# Getting error cannot load such file -- rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn (LoadError), when performing any gem command

Tags: ios, ruby, macos, cocoapods

I am trying to create cocoa-pod framework and trying to create pod spec file but it is giving following error.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:1395:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `require'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'

ruby -v : ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]

which ruby : /usr/bin/ruby
```

I have tried following command, but same result.

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable 
install Ruby with rvm install 2.5.3

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:1395:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `require'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system...........Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.
.
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-2.5.3',
please read /Users/Bhavesh_Mac/.rvm/log/1545279328_ruby-2.5.3/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Comment: Format question properly please.

Comment: macOs version? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53856625/ruby-error-after-upgrading-os-to-mojave-and-installing-xcode-10-1 ?

Comment: I agree: use rbenv to install an up to date Ruby. I find the Mac OS ruby 2.3.0 pretty much useless.

Comment: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.5.3`. [Don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/).

Comment: OS version is macOS-Mojave, and @anothermh I have tried given command giving same error.

Comment: If you're getting the same exact error then I'm guessing you have not correctly installed RVM. It's hard to help you when you haven't explained what you're doing, how the error gets generated, or asked a question.

Comment: Someone post an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53856625/ruby-error-after-upgrading-os-to-mojave-and-installing-xcode-10-1) to this question (that seems this exact one). Have you tried it? `running sudo gem update --system 2.7.4`

Comment: It seems like downgrading to 2.7.4 is a workaround ...

Answer (score -1):

This is likely related to issue [#2535](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2535) in rubygems fixed in [release 3.0.1](https://blog.rubygems.org/2018/12/23/3.0.1-released.html).

Try `gem update --system`